# Problemas de lectura con CSV y PHP

Tags: php, bash, csv, utf-8, terminal

Les comento mi problema:

Yo descargo desde Facebook una lista de potenciales clientes obtenida oir canoalas de publicidad. Ese archivo está en formato CSV UTF-16.

Lo que hago primero que nada para modificar el encoding y pasarlo a UTF-8 es:

```
iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 ingreso.csv > datos-facebook.csv;
chmod 777 datos-facebook.csv;
```

De esta manera modifico el encoding y genero un nuevo archivo con el encoding de UTF-8.

Luego, por medio de `$file = fopen('datos-facebook.csv', 'r');` abro el archivo, chequeo que no esté vacío y luego lo recorro usando `while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE)` y almaceno los resultados del `while` en variables que luego inserto en la db.

El problema que estoy teniendo es que **sí o sí** tengo que entrar al archivo CSV (con Open Office) y apretar guardar y salir y ahí me funciona perfecto el código. En cambio, si no hago ese paso extra, no me lee el archivo.

Me puse a comparar el archivo original y el que abrí y apreté guardar y la diferencia que noté es que me saca las comillas (`"   "`) de cada texto. ¿Alguien tiene idea cómo hacer esto? Porque no estoy pudiendo leer ningún dato a menos que haga ese paso extra.

Comment: prueba agregar a a `fgetcsv` el parámetro `$enclosure = '"'` para indicar que las cadenas están encerradas por comillas.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho asi? while (($line = fgetcsv($file,$enclosure = '"')) !== FALSE)?? Probe y no sucedio nada..si sirve de dato, cuando lo abro con el open office aparecen marcada la opcion "Tabulador"

Comment: Puede ser entonces que el `tab` sea el separador de columnas, prueba entonces indicarlo en `fgetcsv` con el parámetro `$delimiter = "\t"`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Lo mismo (N), es muy raro! se puede poner mas de un delimiter?

Comment: Efectivamente,raro. Prueba compartir algún ejemplo de este archivo aunque sea algunas filas,como para mirarlo un poco.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Te paso un link a mi google drive para uqe puedas ver el codigo! Gracias! https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hewxeOVC3fkx2Bwu_vG5gEkXgl-7OZ3bskI5iWvcN-E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Lo que decía es que compartas el archivo `datos-facebook.csv`, el código pareciera estar bien.